# Export sql records with bash

Tags: mysql, bash

i do this command in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Shell command to create db
source ../db.config

mysql -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME > ../sql/get_tables.sql
```

That sql file do a selection in a database.
So i need to have the query's result in a file. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what is in your `../db.config` but the answer should be something along these lines:

```
mysqlcmd="mysql -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -s -B -q"
echo "USE $DB_NAME;\nSELECT something FROM $DB_NAME;" | $mysqlcmd > outfile
```

Comment: `echo -e "...\n ..."`: use `echo -e` to inlude newline chars